# How Python String array work?

Tags: python, string

i have a python string
word = helloworld
the answer for
word[1:9:2]  will be given as "elwr". How this is happening? Thank you!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're asking for an explanation of Python's slice notation. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/201359) for details. In particular, notice that:

```
word = 'helloworld'
word[1:9:2]
```

... Is stating that a new slice should be created, beginning at index 1, up to (and not including) index 9, taking one element every two indexes in the string. In other words, create a new string with the following elements:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
h e l l o w o r l d
  ^   ^   ^   ^
```

... And that's how you obtain `'elwr'` as a result.

Answer (score 1):

This means that you are taking a sub-string from position[1] to position[9] and in that you are taking only the 2nd letter.
Sub-string would be something like :

```
elloworld
```

and since you are taking the character at index 2 from that it would be :

```
elwr
```

Also its not an array. Its just a string.

Answer (score 0):

array[begin:end:step]

`word[1:9:2]` means you begin at index 1, and up until index 9, take every second letter.

Comment: There are no arrays in Python.

Answer (score 0):

That is array slicing - `word[start_pos:end_pos:step]`, where `start_pos` and `end_pos` are zero-indexed and `step` is the value at which the index is incremented on each iteration.  The character/element at `end_pos` is omitted from the result.

```
|h|e|l|l|o|w|o|r|l|d|
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  ^---------------^
  start           end
```

Since `step = 2` in your example, we would just take every other character from the range above.

```
>>> word = "helloworld"
>>> word[1]
'e'
>>> word[1:9]
'elloworl'
>>> word[1:9:2]
'elwr'
```